# LinearLayout not found - Axml Splash Screen In Xamarin (Forms/Android)

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, splash-screen

I am trying to make a splash screen for the android version of my xamarin forms app. I have a really large image for the splash and when I try and implement the splash screen like I have in previous apps (using a layer list, [following the official guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/user-interface/splash-screen)).

Unfortunately my image is too big and runs off the screen on all devices I've tested, so I need a little more control over my splash screen.

I've seen some posts (fairly old by now) about using an .axml layout as a splash screen:

- [post 1 - adding label or text tag in layer list](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101710/adding-label-or-text-tag-in-layer-list)
- [post 2 - set splash as axml](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/101291/set-splashscreen-as-axml-file)

They look very similar to how I had already done this in the past. I have created a screen layout in **Resource/Layout/Splash.axml**, this previews fine and looks good to go...

I have the following in my **MainActivity.cs**

```
[Activity(Theme = "@style/Theme.Splash", MainLauncher = true, NoHistory = true)]
public class SplashActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Splash);
        this.StartActivity(typeof(MainActivity));
    }
}
```

in my **Styles.xml** file I have the following splash theme (that works for layer lists)

```
<style name="Theme.Splash" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@layout/Splash</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Now when I run the app I get the following error:

Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException

```
{Android.Views.InflateException: Class not found LinearLayout ---> 
Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
Didn't find class "LinearLayout" on path: 
DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.company.splashtest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.company.splashtest-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.company.splashtest-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

My Layout looks like this, and it DOES render in the designer previewer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/customblue"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px">
    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/splash_icon_alpha"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0.0dp" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Build and Migrate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:text="Company © 2018"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView1" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I can't see any reason for it to not find the android linear layout, the cases also appear to be correct. Any ideas on how I can fix this without messing about with png resizing or png text (I'd sooner see a blank splash than a png resizing monstrosity).

Any ideas? perhaps there is a way to manipulate images in a layer list?

Thanks